# How to create arrays inside array if match condition on Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example I have an array

```
g = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

And as a result I need

```
f = [0,0,0,[1,1,1],0,[1,1],0,0,1,0,0,[1,1,1,1],0,0,0,[1,1,1]]
```

Need to join elements (1) only if they appear two or more times in sequence.

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: Just have no idea how to do that..

Comment: Well, here's an idea: loop through your source array and check elements. If it's not `1`, append it to result array. If it is `1`, append it to temporary array. If it's not `1` again, append that temp array to result array.

Comment: You need to show code that demonstrates you've tried to solve the problem yourself, and tell us why it didn't work. Otherwise it looks like you're asking us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented the idea of Sergio Tulentsev

```
g = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
f = []
ones = []
g.each { |x|
  if x == 1
    ones << x
  else
    if ones.size > 1
      f << ones
    elsif ones.size == 1
      f += ones
    end
    ones = []
    f << x
  end
}
if ones.size > 1
  f << ones
elsif ones.size == 1
  f += ones
end
```

**UPDATE**

alternative

```
g = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
f = []
g.each { |x|
  if x == 1
    f << [] if ! f.last.is_a? Array
    f.last << x
  else
    f << x
  end
}
f.each_with_index { |x,i| f[i] = 1 if x == [1] }
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work, too:

```
g.chunk{ |e| e }.flat_map { |a, b| a == 0 || b.length == 1 ? b : [b] }
#=> [0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1], 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 1], 0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: As you already have reduced it,so why not `g.chunk{ |e| e }.flat_map { |a, b| a == 0 || b.length == 1 ? b : [b] }` ? :))

Comment: @Priti thanks for the pointer, I thought `flat_map` would flatten `[b]`

Comment: *+1*..`chunk` is good method to handle this..It will work.. I checked.. :) feeling jealous on you.. why did I not think till that part..:))) :D

Comment: Can you do a quick `benchmark` on this.. I am now away from machine...thus asking you to do.. :)) very eager to see which `chunk` version is fast.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
g.inject([]) do |ary, i|
  if i == 0 or ary.last == 0
    ary << i
  else
    ary[-1] = Array(ary.last) << i
    ary
  end
end

=> [0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1], 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 1], 0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1]]
```

This should be in O(n) runtime.

FYI: `Array(thing)` wraps `thing` in an array (`[thing]`) unless it is already an array.

Comment: Sorry,on the first place i didn't include your one to the benchmark report... Thanks for adding that.. *+1* to you also.. :))

Comment: Don't be sorry! I don't have a problem adding it myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

[**Enumerable#chunk**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) will be a great option for this.

```
g = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
p g.chunk{|i| i == 0}.to_a
# >> [[true, [0, 0, 0]], [false, [1, 1, 1]], [true, [0]],
# [false, [1, 1]], [true, [0, 0]], [false, [1]],
# [true, [0, 0]], [false, [1, 1, 1, 1]], 
# [true, [0, 0, 0]], [false, [1, 1, 1]]]
ar = g.chunk{|i| i == 0}.each_with_object([]) do |(e1,e2),a|
    (!e1 && e2.size > 1) ? a.concat([e2]) :  a.concat(e2)
end
p ar
# >> [0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1], 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
#    [1, 1, 1, 1], 0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1]
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

g = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report('stefan') { n.times { g.chunk{ |e| e }.flat_map { |a, b| a == 0 || b.length == 1 ? b : [b] } } }
  x.report('priti') { n.times { g.chunk{|i| i == 0}.each_with_object([]){|(e1,e2),a| (!e1 && e2.size > 1) ? a.concat([e2]) :  a.concat(e2)} } }
  x.report('tessi') { n.times { g.inject([]) { |ary, i| (i == 0 or ary.last == 0) ? ary << i : (ary[-1] = Array(ary.last) << i); ary }}}
end

                      user     system      total        real
stefan           11.860000   0.000000  11.860000 ( 11.890553)
priti            13.360000   0.000000  13.360000 ( 13.406585)
tessi             5.650000   0.000000   5.650000 (  5.666377)
```

Comment: Added my implementation to your benchmark, hope it is OK for you.

Comment: @tessi I have no problem.. You can add it.. please go ahead.. :)